# PeerJS server setup: Command Not Found

Tags: node.js, server, peerjs

I am attempting to set up a simple WebRTC video chat app, and have decided to employ peerjs for the process. Currently, I am merely trying to set up a server through the command line, but am facing some errors. After `npm install peer -g` I am trying to use `peerjs --port 3001` but keep recieving this error:

```
-bash: peerjs: command not found
```

In both the git repository, and most help videos I can find, this is the way to go about it, however, for some reason, I am getting the error above while they are not. Any suggestions?

Thank you for your answers!